# Time complexity of Catalan number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

The below solution is taken from Stack Overflow which has a very large number of
up votes and it was accepted also, but I have a very very small doubt in this.

The solution is the exact copy I didn't change anything. Since the question is very old, no one seems to reply there.

The following function produces the nth number in Catalan numbers. Actually I have doubt regarding the time complexity of this problem.

```
int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n==0 || n==1)
        return 1;
    
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        sum += catalan(i)*catalan(n-i);
    return sum;
}
```

Here is the solution:

> **My doubt:**
>
> Why is it $c(n+1)-c(n)=2+2c(n)$ ? It should be $c(n+1)-c(n)=2c(n)$ because all terms till $c(n-1)$ will be cancelled in line number 6.

To evaluate the complexity, let us focus on the number of recursive calls performed, let $C(n)$.

A call for $n$ implies exactly $2(n-1)$ recursive calls, each of them adding their own costs, $2(C(1)+C(2)+...C(n-1))$.

A call for $n+1$ implies exactly $2n$ recursive calls, each of them adding their own costs, $2(C(1)+C(2)+...C(n-1)+C(n))$.

By difference, $C(n+1)-C(n) = 2+2C(n)$, which can be written $C(n) = 2+3C(n-1)$.

```
C(1) = 0
C(2) = 2+2C(1) = 2+3C(0) = 2
C(3) = 4+2(C(1)+C(2)) = 2+3C(2) = 8
C(3) = 6+2(C(1)+C(2)+C(3)) = 2+3C(3) = 26
C(4) = 8+2(C(1)+C(2)+C(3)+C(4)) = 2+3C(4) = 80
...
C(n) = 2n-2+2(C(1)+C(2)+...C(n-1)) = 2+3C(n-1)
```

To solve this recurrence easily, notice that

```
C(n)+1 = 3(C(n-1)+1) = 9(C(n-2)+1) = ...3^(n-2)(C(2)+1) = 3^(n-1)
```

Hence, for $n>1$ the exact formula is

```
C(n) = 3^(n-1)-1
```

The number of calls to `Catalan(1)` (constant time), is also $C(n)$, and the numbers of adds or multiplies are $\frac{C(n)}{2}$ each.

It is easy to reduce the complexity from $O(3^n)$ to $O(2^n)$ by noting that all terms in the loop (except the middle one) are computed twice - but that still doesn't make it an acceptable implementation :)

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is $c(n)$, what is $C(n)$? What is  ref [1]?

Comment: Don't forget the actual calls themselves in addition to the costs internally within the calls. That is to line 3 of the solution you must add the $2(n-1)$ from line 2 and to line 5 add $2n$ from line 4.

Comment: The time complexity can be improved to $\mathcal{O}(n)$ if each call to $\operatorname{catalan}(n)$ is [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: @gammatester, the OP's question is in the highlighted "my doubt" paragraph, which refers to a formula a few paragraphs later.  Almost everything other than the "my doubt" paragraph is taken verbatim from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371612/catalan-numbers-recursive-function-time-complexity -- including an apparent typo in which $C(3)$ is listed twice, once with the computed value $8$ and again with the computed value $26$. (To the OP: It would help readers here to link to the original; until I found it, it was unclear what you were quoting and what you were saying on your own.)

Comment: Also, did you leave a comment there asking your "my doubt" question? The answerer, Yves Daoust, is an active participant, at least at MSE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the content is nearly copied verbatim from https://stackoverflow.com/q/27371612/1110928, and the question could be clarified as a comment on the original SO post.